# ios block example. how to create block objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have got two `UIViewController`:

- MainVC
- PickerVC

In main view controller I have IBAction method:
- showPickerView

In this method I need to create block that will present PickerVC view and wait me while I choose something value on PickerVC view and press Done button.

In this block I need to implement callback that will invoke method in MainVC after I press on button Done.

So, I have used block before, but I don't know how to implement it by myself.

I think first part will be look like this:

```
- (IBAction)showPickerView {
   __block PickerVC *pickerVC = [[PickerVC alloc] init];
   [pickerVC setFinishBlock:^{
      // Do something after user press on Done button
   }];
   [pickerVC setFailedBlock:^{
      // Do something if something wrong (but this method optional)
   }];
   [pickerVC showPicker];
}
```

Comment: [This page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) has all the info that you need.

Comment: if you need a callback why don't you try to create a protocol and use the delegate scheme? or why don't you use the `NSNotificationCenter`...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in the header of PickerVC two typedefs

```
typedef void (^FinishBlock)();
typedef void (^FailedBlock)();
```

and your declaration of setFinishedBlock takes the FinishBlock

```
- (void)setFinishBlock:(FinishBlock)finishBlock;
- (void)setFailedBlock:(FailedBlock)failedBlock;
```

Make an iVar for each block

```
@interface PickerVC : UIViewController
{
  FinishBlock _finishBlock;
  FailedBlock _failedBlock;
}
```

In your definition of `setFinishedBlock:` and `setFailedBlock:` set the parameter to the iVars

As soon as PickerVC fails or finishes call `_failedBlock` or `_finishedBlock`.

The `__block` statement is used for variables to stay in memory if they are used in a block. So you don't need it in the above code

Comment: like a c function _failedBlock();

Comment: Make sure to check for nil first: `if (_failedBlock) _failedBlock();`